# MS Excel, Filter from Master Tab

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of equipment information and product IDs, etc that I am trying to use the a tab called Master to pull in information to another tab for shorting and filtering. For Example, I have all my equipment information filled out in the Master tab under column AA, AB, AC & AD and I would go down column A and place the required qty number is I need that equipment and the tab I have labeled A would pull in this information in.

This is what I have so far that works. The issue is that I dont know how to make it look at the entire column A and column AA.

`=FILTER(Master!AA6:AA8,Master!A6:A8>0)` - This Code is copied into the tab called A

I tried this code with ultimate failure.

`=FILTER(Master!$AA$6:AA,Master!$A$6:$A>0)`

Suggestion on how to get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data (from your Master) plus the expected output on sheet A. It will be much easier to help you with that information. Reading [ask] and [repro] and using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) will help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

`=FILTER(Master!$AA:AA,Master!$A:$A>0)` is a whole column reference notation.

`=FILTER(Master!$AA:AA,(Master!$A:$A>0)*(ROW(Master!$A:$A)>5))` is a whole column reference notation excluding the first 5 rows.